# Reverse and Join Functions Outputting Original Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reverse

I have an array, we'll call it *arr* and assign it a value of [a, a, b, c, d]. I am trying to first reverse the array and then join it together to make a string. When I execute the code:

```
arr.reverse().join('');
```

I would expect to get an output of (minus quotations):

```
'dcbaa'
```

However, what I actually get is:

```
'aabcd'
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Am I just not understanding the core functionality of the code I'm writing? Is the reverse function returning the reverse and then throwing it away as soon as it gets to the join function? I was under the impression that a good way to reverse a string was to use:

```
str.split('').reverse().join('');
```

I am just taking the last part of it as I already have the array. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT FOR CONTEXT:
I am writing a function to look for palindromes. I take a string that is passed to the function and then find the longest palindrome in that string.

```
longestPalindrome=function(s){
  var strlen = 0;  
  var stringArr = s.toLowerCase().split('');
  var chunk = '';

  if(s.length === 0){
    return strlen;
  }

  //for loop to go through each letter
  for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    //for loop to grab increasing chunks of array (a, ab, abc, abcd, etc.)
    for(var j = 0; j < s.length - i; j++){
      //Grab piece of string and convert to array
      chunk = stringArr.slice(i, (s.length - j));
      //View new array
      console.log(chunk);
      //Reverse chunk for later comparison
      var chunkReverse = chunk.reverse();
      //Check to see what reverse of array would be
      console.log(chunkReverse);
      //Create string from chunk
      chunk = chunk.join('');
      //view string from former chunk array
      console.log(chunk);
      //Create string from reversed array
      chunkReverse = chunkReverse.join('');
      //View reversed string from chunk array
      console.log(chunkReverse);
    }
  }

  return strlen;
}
```

The outputs I get from the above give me (with dummy data from original post):

```
[a,a,b,c,d]
[d,c,b,a,a]
aabcd
aabcd
```

I hope that this helps clarify.

Comment: `['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'].reverse().join('')` definitely outputs the string `'dcbaa'`. Please [edit] your question to show your `arr.reverse().join('');` line in context, because what you have shown isn't enough to reproduce the problem. Note that you would need to do something with the return value of `.join()`, and also `arr.reverse()` actually changes the array in place so if you execute `arr.reverse().join('');` twice in a row you would get `'dcbaa'` then `'aabcd'`.

Comment: I have made edits to help clarify the original post.

Comment: Thank you nnnnnn for your assistance and time.

Comment: If you just want  to check if a string is palindrome or not better try this, `let isPalindrome = (str) => str === str.split('').reverse().join('')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method mutates the original array and returns that array. To prevent that from happening, copy the original array before reversing it by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```js
var chunkReverse = chunk.slice().reverse();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It does. Thank you for your assistance and time.